# Protocol buffer serialization Golang

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, dialogflow-es

I am using [DialogFlow V2 official GoLang SDK](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/dialogflow/v2). In my webhook, I am returning a payload, which I'm obtaining using the function [GetWebhookPayload()](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/dialogflow/v2#QueryResult.GetWebhookPayload).

This returns [*google_protobuf4.Struct](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/struct#Struct). I would like to turn this struct into a `map[string]interface{}`. How is this possible?

This is what the struct looks like when serialized:

```
"payload": {
        "fields": {
            "messages": {
                "Kind": {
                    "ListValue": {
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "Kind": {
                                    "StructValue": {
                                        "fields": {
                                            "title": {
                                                "Kind": {
                                                    "StringValue": "Hi! How can I help?"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "type": {
                                                "Kind": {
                                                    "StringValue": "message"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

What I essentially need is for it to be serialized as such:

```
"payload": {
    "messages": [
        {
            "title": "Hi! How can I help?",
            "type": "message"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: implement unmarshaler interface to fetch the data from json you need

Comment: data returned could be in any format there is no structure

Comment: `message` key and `StringValue` key will not going to change right ?

Comment: `messages` will not change it will always contain a list of unknown objects

Comment: use interface{} for that and get the value from deep until string not found

Comment: sorry I don't understand what I should do

Comment: This link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48167286/golang-json-and-slices-of-interface/48169341#48169341 might help to get the value from nested json with unknown objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170623/discussion-between-himanshu-and-kskyriacou).

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using [jsonpb](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb).

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"

    "github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb"
)

func main() {
    ...

    payload := qr.GetWebhookPayload()
    b, marshaler := bytes.Buffer{}, jsonpb.Marshaler{}
    if err := marshaler.Marshal(&b, payload.GetFields()["messages"]); err != nil {
        // handle err
    }

    msgs := []interface{}{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b.Bytes(), &msgs); err != nil {
        // handle err
    }

    // msgs now populated
}
```